# New filter condition: Add cart id as attribute to shopping cart rule => Solving discount on first item only

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, discount

we have been trying to solve this for ages. Apply 50% on first product in cart only. As I understand this cannot be done as is. Magento 1.9.0.1

So I was thinking. Can I add a new filter condition? that being the position/id in the cart object. Then we set IF CART ID = 1

**Question:** Would this be very hard to accomplish? Or is there a smart way to create an ingenious extension to do this?

Any help appreciated - and if I find the solution I will share it here. I see this questiion been asked many times.

[image]

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11864012/shopping-cart-rules-with-custom-condition